# class as a property of another class with reflection C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties

See below code and can someone help me....

```
public class person
{ 
  Public string name  { get; set; };  
  Public personDetails Pdetails { get; };
}

public class personDetails
{
  Public bool hasChild  { get; set; }
  Public string ChildName  { get; set; }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Type type = asm.GetType(person);

    object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type); 


    PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty("Pdetails ", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    if (null != prop && prop.CanWrite)
    {
        prop.SetValue(classInstance, null , null);
    }
}
```

getting Error for property not found.

Comment: Capitalize your type names! Also, What exactly is this `string?` ? String *is* a reference type.

Comment: BTW, your casing hurts my eyes! Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx rules for capitalization.

Comment: are you writing code like that or it is only so ugly for SO? `type.GetProperty("Pdetails "` property names cannot contain spaces.

Comment: This code won't compile since you don't have a trailing semicolon after `Type type = asm.GetType(person)`

Comment: thanks for replay , i m try with dynamic load dll with console application. my question is how to set member of class personDetails property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property `Pdetails` is not `public`, so your `BindingFlags` should be

```
BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
```

Also, see Joel Etherton's answer.

Comment: thanks for replay , i m try with dynamic load dll with console application. my question is how to set member of class personDetails property

Answer (score 3):

Class members are `private` by default. Make your properties `public` and it should work. Also, remove that extra space on the property string: `"Pdetails"`.

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra space character in your property name. `"Pdetails "` is not the same as `"Pdetails"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Type type = asm.GetType("person");
```

You can only pass type of the object in string format to the asm.GetType function.
Another this is that where did you declare the asm object. if you didnt, then define it first.

Answer (score 0):

```
static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
        {
            var objType = obj.GetType();
            var prop = objType.GetProperty(propertyName);

            return prop.GetValue(obj, null);
        }
        static void SetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName, int values)
        {
            var objType = obj.GetType();
            var prop = objType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            prop.SetValue(obj, values, null);
        }
```

Thanks for you support i have use upper code to resolved my problem.